Is there any simple way to transform jsonb field into csv?
I have a model with a jsonb field where responses from a third-party service are stored. The response changes periodically; some fields are added, some disappear. I want to generate a CSV from a sample of records. To do this, I need to gather all possible fields from the sample and turn them into columns in the CSV file.

You should add some example to make question understandable. For example such JSONB could have nested keys / arrays etc.

Just do it? You should at least attempt display an attempt at solving the problem and an example of the data you're converting an expected result. This is just lazy. https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Pivoting rows to columns is painful because SQL needs to know the schema of SELECT before it starts.  Since a CSV file is just data, I have done something along these lines before:
with invals (id, jdata) as (
  values 
  (1, '{"a": 11, "b": 12, "c": 12}'::jsonb),
  (2, '{"d": 24, "e": 25, "f": 26}'::jsonb),
  (3, '{"a": 31, "c": 33, "e": 35}'::jsonb),
  (4, '{"a": 41, "b": 42, "c": 43, "d": 44, "f": 46}'::jsonb)
), allkeys as (
  select distinct k 
    from invals 
         cross join lateral jsonb_each(jdata) as e(k,v)
)
select -999 as id, string_agg(k, ',' order by k) as d
  from allkeys
union all
select id, string_agg(coalesce(i.jdata->>k, ''), ',' order by k)
  from invals i
       cross join allkeys a
 group by id
 order by id
;

Working fiddle

Assuming your data isn't nested:
# bin/rails g model Item data:jsonb --no-timestamps

Item.create([
  {data: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}},
  {data: {b: 4, c: 5, d: 6}},
  {data: {c: 7, d: 8, e: 9}},
  {data: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}},
])

require "csv"

items = Item.all
columns = items.flat_map { |item| item.data.keys }.uniq

CSV.open("data.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << columns
  items.each do |item|
    csv << item.data.values_at(*columns)
  end
end

$ cat data.csv
a,b,c,d,e,x,y,z
1,2,3,,,,,
,4,5,6,,,,
,,7,8,9,,,
,,,,,0,0,0


even easier with smarter_csv gem:
require 'smarter_csv'
SmarterCSV.generate('data.csv) do |writer|
  writer << items.map(&:data)
end

same output file
